# Size of the intersection of a $p$-Sylow subgroup and a normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Assume $G$ is a group whose size is $(p^r)*m$, where $p$ is prime and $p$ doesn't divide $m$. Let $P$ be a $P$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$.
Lagrange's theorem gives us that the size of $H$ must be $(p^s)*k$, $s \le r$ and $k\mid m$. I need to show that the size of $P\cap H$; the intersection of P and H is $p^s$, and nothing I tried works. Any ideas?

Comment: $P \cap H$ is a subgroup of both $P$ and $H$, so its order must divide the order of $P$ and the order of $H$. (This doesn't quite get you all the way there, but it tells you that the order of $P \cap H$ must divide $p^s$.)

Comment: Hint: A Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ (which has order $p^s$)  is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, which is conjugate in $G$ to $P$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)